# How to return error from Auth0 hooks

Tags: auth0

If I want to return custom error from Rules I simply do callback(new UnauthorizedError('Custom error message here')) but how do I do the same thing with Hooks?

callback('error message');
callback(new Error('error message'));

Those didn't worked and "UnauthorizedError" is undefined in Hooks. Whatever I do, on front-end side I always get "WE'RE SORRY, SOMETHING WENT WRONG WHEN ATTEMPTING TO SIGN UP." and when I inspect result of requested I see that there is no difference, each time "InternalExtensibilityError" comes.

Why do I want to return error from Hooks? I run extra validation for sign-up there.

Answer (score 2):

Now it is possible to send custom error messages in hooks.
I extracted below code snippet from Auth0's documentation on hooks.

```js
module.exports = function (user, context, cb) {
  const isUserDenied = ...; // determine if a user should be allowed to register

  if (isUserDenied) {
    const LOCALIZED_MESSAGES = {
      en: 'You are not allowed to register.',
      es: 'No tienes permitido registrarte.'
    };

    const localizedMessage = LOCALIZED_MESSAGES[context.renderLanguage] || LOCALIZED_MESSAGES['en'];
    return cb(new PreUserRegistrationError('Denied user registration in Pre-User Registration Hook', localizedMessage));
  }
};
```

Here is the original link (https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/extensibility-points/pre-user-registration)

Comment: This still produces the same response message from the question above. Looks like it has not yet been fixed.

Comment: According to auth0, your tenant must be configured to use the Universal Login - New Experience.

Comment: Do you mean the classic Universal Login does not work seamlessly with hooks?

Comment: No, it is clearly mentioned in the link I have posted above.

Comment: Anyway i moved on from using auth0 hooks after failing multiple times. A couple of people are facing the same problem though. This is a question i asked in the auth0 community a month back and we are waiting for their response.
https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-pre-user-registration-hook-shows-different-message-on-universal-signup-page/45126/2

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, returning custom errors from hooks to the top-level API, `/dbconnections/signup` in this case is not possible in Auth0. This is documented in the bottom of this [page](https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/extensibility-points/pre-user-registration).

Note that Hooks is still in Beta, and this enhancement request is one of the most asked for features and it is currently in our backlog. We cannot give an ETA for this yet. You can submit your feedback to the Product [here](https://auth0.com/feedback).